# How to resolve the migration problem python?

Tags: python, migration, python-django-storages

I have a problem with migration in this model.
So this is my initial class Post, it works perfectly(migration worked):

**Initial Class Post**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to add a new column:

```
photos = models.ImageField(upload_to="/images/", default = None)
```

I deleted all migrations and so when i used makemigrations it works, but when i try to migrate i get nothing:

**PowerShell Result:**

```
Apply all migrations: blog
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

When i try to fake migrations it also is not working:

**PowerShell Result:**

```
Target specific migration: 0001_initial, from blog
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

After i run the server i get this error:

**Trying to acces my local website:**

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Administrator PC\Desktop\mysite\blog\templates\blog\base.html, error at line 6

no such column: blog_post.photos
    {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

        {% if title %}
            <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
```

Please help i don't know what to try more. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use your app name in migration command like this

```
python manage.py makemigrations blog
python manage.py migrate blog
```

Comment: Probably migration mismatched, you can delete your database and all migration file, also don't forget to reserve necessary data from database in separate file

Comment: I deleted all migration file hopefully it will work. But can you say me what means the second part, i am new and i maybe done it but i am not sure.

Comment: Backup your all necessary data if needed

Comment: Go to the link, here are some example about backup and restore, this is called dumpdata and loaddata https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata

Comment: So now I need to dumpdata the migrations?

Comment: No you need dumpdata if you not want to lose your data, because if you delete database data will be lose

Comment: And how this will help me? I tried to fake this didn't worked, I tried so many things, but this is not helping.